# Heroku throwing an error when I try to push?

Tags: python, node.js, heroku

I have an old project from 2 years ago that I would like to put onto another Heroku (so it is accessible if the first one stops working). Originally I build this project on Linux, and now I'm on Windows.

I cloned the Github project, added the .env file (for API calls), and tried to push it to the new Heroku page. It didn't work at first so I installed Nodejs and Python buildpacks. I also renamed master to main.

I've been getting errors & trying to work through them, but I don't understand this last one:

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
remote: Waiting for release... failed.
```

After Googling for answers, this is what I've tried sofar:

```
pip install virtualenv
> Requirement already satisfied:

virtualenv --python C:\Python27\python.exe venv
> 'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

python virtualenv --python C:\Python27\python.exe venv
> python: can't open file 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\PROJECT from PROJECT\virtualenv': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any idea what I need to do? I need to create a PYTHONPATH environment variable? Or I need to activate the project in a virtual environment? Or something else?

Comment: None of those commands have anything to do with this error. They operate locally, but the issue is on Heroku. Have you declared Django as a dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy my old Heroku app onto a different Heroku account:

1: Clone the app from Heroku onto my local machine:

```
heroku git:clone -a myapp
```

(Heroku doesn't recommend this because it is not a storage repository. But since I knew my app was working, I wanted the exact working code.)

2: Logout of my first Heroku account and login to my second one. Then change my login credentials in the command line:

```
heroku login
```

3: Remove the original Heroku branch:

```
git remote rm heroku
```

4: Add the new Heroku branch:

```
heroku git:remote -a example-app
```

5: My original app uses React and Python, so I had to make sure both buildpacks were installed in the settings:
heroku/nodejs
heroku/python

6: Try to push to Heroku; this failed for me:

```
git push heroku main
```

7: My first error was I didn't specify which version of Python the app needs so Heroku was automatically using the latest one. My app needs old 3.7.1 and Heroku was giving it new 3.10.4. To fix I created a runtime.txt file on the root directory:

```
python-3.7.13
```

(Heroku doesn't support 3.7.1 anymore. So I tried 3.7.13, which is the oldest one they do support.)

8: My second error was this:

```
" ImportError: cannot import name 'FieldDoesNotExist' from 'django.db.models.fields' (/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/init.py)"
```

This is my mistake since I didn't clearly specify which version of Django to use.

9: In the requirements.txt file I changed it to this:

```
Django==3.0.6
```

10: And then I was able to push the code to Heroku, the app works just like the original:

```
git push heroku main
```